# How can I randomly select between a structure that initializes variables?

Tags: python

I am attempting to assign strings to variables, and then randomly select from those variables.

The problem is that I can't find a way to:

1. Randomly select from a class, or some other structure that allows for me to initialize the variables within the structure, or
2. Choose from a list of variables, where I am not required to type information redundantly

Ideally, I would like something like this:

```
class Websites:
    google = "https://google.com"
    twitter = "https://twitter.com"
    instagram = "https://instagram.com"
```

and then be able to choose from those:

```
print(random.choice(Websites))
```

I've also tried creating a pseudo-switch statement:

```
from project.config import Websites

def switch_website(random_site):
    _ = Websites

    return {
         1: _.google
         2: _.twitter,
         3: _.instagram
    }[random_site]
```

But this requires me to put the variable name in both the class and the dictionary, which is problematic because the final list will be quite large, and will need to be amended with extra sites later on.

My apologies if I use incorrect terminology, I started using Python yesterday.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should use instance variables, and instantiate your class, then `random.choice(list(vars(instance).values()))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ideal solution! Thank you!

Comment: In hindsight, the above solution might not be ideal, as it seemed to be occasionally giving me garbage values from vars(instance). Not too sure on this one, please others chime in if you know! ^_^

Comment: What does "garbage values" mean? `vars(instance)` will *only ever return the namespace dict of an instance*. So if there are garbage values, that means your instance has garbage values (whatever that means exactly).

Comment: Not sure, exactly (still super new to Python). See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56137015/11471579

Comment: Because in that case you are looking at `vars(MyClass)` and not `vars(instance_of_my_class)`, which is why I originally said "use instance variables, and instantiate your class". You are using class variables and the class, not an instance.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dictionary for this:

```
import random

Websites = {
    "google": "https://google.com",
    "twitter": "https://twitter.com",
    "instagram": "https://instagram.com",
}

print(random.choice(list(Websites.items())))
```

If you want just the URL part, use `values()` instead of `items()`:

```
print(random.choice(list(Websites.values())))
```

Comment: Yes, I believe this is exactly what I needed, thank you! I just didn't realize `values()` and `items()` were an option. Great to know! I will do more research on what all can be done with dictionaries. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you need just get random from several values, create list of these values and use random choice.

```py
import random

google = "https://google.com"
twitter = "https://twitter.com"
instagram = "https://instagram.com"

site_list = [google, twitter, instagram]

print(random.choice(site_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are trying to find a dictionary. These let you store key-value pairs like your example (a class seems inappropriate for this for sure, maybe you are used to defining everything in one like in Java or something). You could accomplish your example like this (there are other ways too I'm sure):

```
import random

websites = {
    'google': "https://google.com",
    'twitter': "https://twitter.com",
    'instagram': "https://instagram.com"
}

website_name_list = list(websites.keys())
print(website_name_list)
random_website_name = random.choice(website_name_list)
print(random_website_name)
corresponding_url = websites[random_website_name]
print(corresponding_url)
```

Where an example output would be

```
['twitter', 'google', 'instagram']
google
https://google.com
```