# What might be causing this Python code to SOMETIMES fail?

Tags: python, selenium

```py
class Websites
    default = 'https://google.com'
    spotify = 'https://spotify.com'
    facebook = 'https://facebook.com'
    twitter = 'https://twitter.com'
```

[...]

```
from websites import Websites

random_website = random.choice(list(vars(Websites).values()))
browser.get(random_website)  # This line fails like 30-50% of the time
```

Note that I am purposefully not using a dictionary here, because I would like to use the random value to get the key.

Debugging, I've found that it will randomly get set to something like this:
`random_website = {getset_descriptor} <attribute '__dict__' of 'Websites' objects>`

I'm really not sure why it wouldn't be working, because I've tested all of the URLs multiple times.

Also note that this application uses threads -- there are multiple instances of this application (usually 4) and at any given time roughly 1-2 fail, in case that might matter. I'm still very new to Python and Selenium (and still not that experienced in coding, honestly). Please let me know if I can provide more information that might be helpful.

Comment: `vars(Websites)` is a dictionary. Just twice as complicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vars(Websites)`

1. is a dictionary
2. has all kinds of objects in it, mostly inherited from `object`

If you print it, you will see all kinds of things like unbound methods and other normal object attributes. This happens because an object's `__dict__` automatically gets some default elements assigned by the `type` metaclass. All these attributes should be dunders.

You therefore have two options:

1. Persist in your current course and filter for dunders:

   ```
   items = [v for k, v in vars(Website).items() if not k.startswith('__')]
   ```

   This is not the recommended approach.
2. Just use a normal dictionary that only contains what you want. You're calling `values` on it either way. If you don't really need the labels, just use a list.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response. I do need the variable names though, and it seems that getting keys from values in dictionaries is not very well supported. Surely there is a way to pick a random variable from a structure and then later get its data?

Comment: @Lo-Phi You need both the value and the key, and getting keys from values is hard, so why not choose a random key, and then get the corresponding value? You can even get both at once by chosing at random from ```websites.items()```.

Comment: @AdeolaBannis Thank you. I actually tried that originally, but I couldn't figure out how to separate the two:

1. I would like to get a key/value pair (randomly)
2. print the key
3. use the value to go to a website

Comment: @Lo-Phi `random_label, random_website = random.choice(websites.items())`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Oh! Wow, didn't know that was possible! Thanks! You're a Mad-man! :P

Answer (score 3):

You laid out your thought process pretty clearly in the comments to Mad Physicists's answer so you just need a mini-tutorial in Python.

A.  How to store the data. As suggested above, a dictionary is probably the best way, with strings as keys and values. You probably want to deal with strings, not with variables.

```
websites = {'default':'https://www.google.com', 'stack':'https://stackoverflow.com'}
```

B.  You can get a list of all the keys in the dictionary, or a list of (key, value) pairs called **tuples**. This means replacing `vars(Websites).values()` with `websites.keys()` or `websites.items()`. Then your code will give you a random key or item.

C. If you chose ```keys()``, then you can just print the random thing you got, and use that key to get the corresponding value from the dictionary.

```
random_key = random.choice(websites.keys())
print(random_key)
random_website = websites[random_key] # this is how you get values using keys
```

D.  If you chose `items()`, then the tuple you got is basically an immutable list (you can't change or assign to either value). You can pull them out by specifying an index in the list. Python indices start at 0.

```
random_item = random.choice(websites.items())
print(random_item) # something like ('default', 'https://www.google.com')
random_key = random_item[0] # this is how you choose an item from a list or tuple
print(random_key)
random_website = random_item[1]
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to change the approach slightly for Python 3:
```python
random_key = random.choice(websites.keys())
```

becomes

```python
random_key = random.choice(list(websites))
```

But this line in particular:
```python
random_website = websites[random_key] # this is how you get values using keys
```

This wasn't mentioned elsewhere (at least nowhere visibly apparent) when I googled for how to get values from keys and things like that.

My code appears to be functioning properly now. Thanks so much!